# How to pass Terraform variables to .yaml files?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, terraform, yaml

I have a terraform module and .yaml docker-compose with service configuration. Yaml have variables such as:

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:${var.image_version}     
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
    mem_limit: ${var.limit}
    mem_reservation: ${var.reservation}
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

and my resource:

```
resource "local_file" "compose" {
  content = file("${var.compose_path}/docker-compose.yml")
  filename = "${path.module}/foo.bar"
}
```

The values is declared in my module. I'm going to use this docker-compose.yml in my project e.g. send to remote server and run there. How can I pass variable values from my module to yaml?

I tried to declare values and do some actions with my yaml such as `resource "local_file"`  to save as file, but .yaml remains without values.

Comment: Can you add the entire code block to the question? I have an idea about the answer but I need to see everything you have currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the `templatefile` built-in function [1]:

```
resource "local_file" "compose" {
  content = templatefile("${var.compose_path}/docker-compose.yml", {
    image_version = var.image_version
    limit         = var.limit       
    reservation   = var.reservation
  })
  filename = "${path.module}/docker-compose.yml"
}
```

This will also require a minor change to the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.2'
services:
  cadvisor:
    image: gcr.io/google-containers/cadvisor:${image_version}     
    container_name: cadvisor
    volumes:
    - /:/rootfs:ro
    - /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:ro
    mem_limit: ${limit}
    mem_reservation: ${reservation}
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile